WPF Checkbox Shows Checkmark Only When Mouse Hovers
I'm working on a Net 8 app in WPF and MVVM. I've got a number of checkboxes bound to bool? properties in the viewmodel. I preset those properties to True in the viewmodel constructor. At runtime, the checkboxes only show the checkmark when the mouse hovers over the checkbox. I wondered if there was something going on with the binding, so I removed the bound property and explicitly set IsChecked to true. I saw the same result. My code that uses the bound properties works as expected, using the IsChecked status of each checkbox.
This is my first Net Core app to use checkboxes. I've done this many times in the Net Framework. I've searched for a solution here and other places, to no avail. Maybe I'm phrasing the question poorly.
Does anyone have any ideas?
A snippet from the viewmodel...
public bool? Use6m { get; set; }

public vmView1()
{
   Use6m = true;
}

A snippet from the view...
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BandCheckboxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Margin="1,1,1,1" >
    <GroupBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="274" Width="167" Margin="10,54,0,0">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <Label Content="Band and Mode" Foreground="LightBlue" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Arial" />
        </GroupBox.Header>

        <Grid>
            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource BandCheckboxStyle}" Content="6m" IsChecked="{Binding Use6m, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="1,-5,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>


My bet would be some strange UI theme ? For me it shows correctly, when I use plain CheckBox with your styles. It shows clear black check mark.

Thanks for the response. No special themes. Just a normal VS2022 Desktop C# project.

If you temporarily remove your style, does that fix your problem? What's the background colour to the check mark going to be? I am wondering about your foreground setter there.

Hi Andy. It was indeed a Checkbox background color issue. I am using a ContentControl on a transparent window to host the views.  I set the background color of the checkbox to transparent, now it works. The problem was the checkmark was the same color as the background, and when I hovered over the checkbox, it received focus and the color changed.
